# How to pass props using styled components?

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, styled-components, react-props

I am trying to build a component that accepts a primary and secondary colour using typescript, react.js and styled-components. I am relatively new to all these technologies. the issue I am having is I can't seem to get the styled component to be able to see the props?
Here is my code so far:

**//Main index file**

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { PropsWithChildren } from 'react'
import { COLOUR } from '../../_core/colours'
import { CloseIcon } from '../../_core/icons/Close'
import { ButtonContainer, Container } from './index.styles'

export interface OverlayProps {
  onClickClose?: () => void
  colour: 'primary' | 'secondary'
}

export const Overlay = ({
  onClickClose,
  colour,
  children,
}: PropsWithChildren<OverlayProps>) => (
  <Container backgroundColour={colour}>
    <ButtonContainer onClick={onClickClose}>
      <CloseIcon fill={COLOUR.primary.blue_slate} variant="fill" />
    </ButtonContainer>
    {children}
  </Container>
)
```

**//styled-component file:**

```
import styled from 'styled-components'
import { COLOUR } from '../../_core/colours'
import { ONBOARDING_MAX_WIDTH, UNIT_2, UNIT_4 } from '../../_core/grid'

export const Container = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: ${UNIT_2};
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: ${ONBOARDING_MAX_WIDTH};
  z-index: 100;
  background-color: ${(props) => {
    switch (props.backgroundColour) {
      case 'primary':
        return COLOUR.tints.pastel_yellow40
      case 'secondary':
        return COLOUR.secondary.white
    }
  }};
`

export const ButtonContainer = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: auto;
  > svg {
    padding: ${UNIT_2};
    height: auto;
    width: ${UNIT_4};
  }
`
```

As you can see I am trying to set a switch which sets background colour depending on the state of colour being primary or secondary. every styled component guide seems to recommend this as the way of doing it, so whats the issue?

Comment: Can you please show the variables like `COLOUR.tints.pastel_yellow40`?

Comment: Hi I'll send it across in a sec, I know that element works though as I have used it in many components. The bit it seems complain about is "props.backgroundColour" in the styles component

Comment: Based on the answer in the link above you could do something like this`const Container = styled.div<{ backgroundColour: string }> //etc...`

Comment: Ahhhh the themeprovider thing should solve my problem let my try it later and I'll get back to you!

Comment: ok that was the answer thank you! I guess it's a Typescript issue then